# Forward traffic to specific IP via SSH SOCKS tunnel

Tags: curl, ssh, iptables, socks

I'm able to SSH into 223.32.11.43 and cURL other servers on it's local network.

This works when I'm SSH'ed into :

```
curl -d '{my: parameter}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" 10.0.30.10
{code:200}
```

On a remote server I've setup a SOCKS tunnel with:

```
ssh -f -N -D 9090 MyUser@223.32.11.43
```

I've tried to setup iptables so I can cURL internal servers on the same network as the remote server:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -s 10.0.30.10 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 223.32.11.43
```

But it seems to fail, at least it times out with I try to cURL:

```
curl -d '{my: parameter}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" 10.0.30.10
...timeout
```

What do to, so I can do the same cURL on my remote server?

Comment: On the second curl request, you probably need to add `--socks5-hostname 223.32.11.43:9090` to tell it to use the socks proxy.  No need for the iptables rule.  The application needs to speak in socks which won't happen with the iptables rule.  It'll just forward to port 80 on destination. Also, I don't think the SSH command is setting up a SOCKS tunnel, just a SSH tunnel.

Comment: Still timeout. Does the remote server needs to have more rules in it's iptables, or is everything tunnelled through the already allowed SOCKS tunnel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

From your remote computer, set up the SOCKS SSH tunnel to the remote server:

```
ssh -D 9090 -f -C -q -N MyUser@remote.ip
```

From the remote computer, issue a request over the tunnel:

```
curl -d '{my: parameter}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--socks5-hostname remote.ip:9090 10.0.30.10
```

Comment: Still getting timeout:

My-Lenovo:~ micniel$ ssh -D 9090 -f -C -q -N MyUser@remote.ip
My-Lenovo:~ micniel$ curl http://10.0.30.10 --socks5-hostname remote.ip:9090
curl: (7) Failed to connect to remote.ip port 9090: Operation timed out

Comment: Just to clarify if it isn't explained good enough in the original post. The local IP 10.0.30.10 is NOT my remote servers local IP. It is a local IP which my remote server can reach.